# CMFCTabCtrl catch tab change event

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, mfc-feature-pack

I want to catch the tab change event of a CMFCTabCtrl. Below is the code I'm trying to do that. But it does not catch the change event.

```
BOOL SurvChatDlg::OnNotify( WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, LRESULT* 
                               pResult ) 
{ 
if(((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code==TCN_SELCHANGE) 
{ 
    int i = m_TabControl.GetActiveTab();
    AfxMessageBox("Changed");
} 
return CDialog::OnNotify( wParam, lParam, pResult ); 
}
```

Comment: It's easier to derive your own class from `CMFCTabCtrl` and add a message handler there.

Comment: What is the message I should handle??..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this forum thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6972224d-f7c7-46c1-b3bb-33d3debd87db/catching-child-window-activation), you need to handle the [AFX_WM_CHANGING_ACTIVE_TAB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb982948.aspx) message sent to the parent window.

[This forum thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e11bdcec-78bf-4b94-8e0b-1d7a8234a931/mfc-mdi-tab-activation) has more code samples.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't catch the event. By the way the app is not a MDI tab application.

Comment: The second forum thread link also shows how to catch the message in `CMainFrame` -- if you do not have a frame window, how are you hosting the tab control?

Comment: I just override the CMFCTabCtrl class and added this line to the MESSAGE_MAP ON_REGISTERED_MESSAGE(AFX_WM_CHANGING_ACTIVE_TAB, &CMyTabCtrl::OnAfxWmChangingActiveTab)

Comment: The `AFX_WM_CHANGING_ACTIVE_TAB` message is not sent to the tab control, it is sent to the parent -- are you embedding the tab control in a dialog or a SDIWindow or which kind of a window?

Comment: It is in an object in a CDialog.

Comment: your reply is not clear enough, is the parent of the tab control your dialog class or an object within the dialog?
The `ON_REGISTERED_MESSAGE(AFX_WM_CHANGING_ACTIVE_TAB...)` should be declared in the class of the parent and should point to a member function in the class of the parent -- see if the function is invoked when you switch tabs

Comment: Sorry for my bad English. ON_REGISTERED_MESSAGE(AFX_WM_CHANGING_ACTIVE_TAB...) is in the CMyTabCtrl class which inherited from the CMFCTabCtrl. And I am using a  CMyTabCtrl object in the CDialog class. Is it clear now?

Comment: Then try moving your `ON_REGISTERED_MESSAGE` and the function to `CDialog`, like `ON_REGISTERED_MESSAGE(AFX_WM_CHANGING_ACTIVE_TAB, &CMyDialog::OnAfxWmChangingActiveTab)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to catch the post tab change, the tab that *will* be active, need **AFX_WM_CHANGE_ACTIVE_TAB** ie;

```
ON_REGISTERED_MESSAGE(AFX_WM_CHANGE_ACTIVE_TAB,OnTabSetActive)

LRESULT CYourClass::OnTabSetActive(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    const int iActiveTab = (int)wParam;
    int iCheckActiveTab = m_wndTabs.GetActiveTab(); //CMFCTabCtrl m_wndTabs;
    m_wndTabs.SetActiveTab(iActiveTab); //good idea to also add this depending on usage.
    return 0;
}
```

And if you require manually changing the tab call using;

```
    SendMessage(AFX_WM_CHANGE_ACTIVE_TAB, iTabNum2ChangeTo, 0);
```

Posted the above after trying to find a solution to my problem where using

```
CMFCTabCtrl::SetActiveTab()
```

would crash but in debug mode only. And this OP was googles top answer.

**AFX_WM_CHANGING_ACTIVE_TAB** appears to catch the event *prior* to the actual tab change, hence why hasn't worked for the OP, and can be checked by;

```
int iCheckActiveTab = m_wndTabs.GetActiveTab();
```